# jboss 4: enable UsersRolesLoginModule, where must users.properties files be placed?

Tags: authentication, jboss

I have an application (CQ5)  that requires enabling unauthenticatedIdentity on jbossdir/conf/login-config.xml
I used:

```
   <authentication>
      <login-module code = "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
         flag = "required" >
      <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">nobody</module-option>
    </login-module>
   </authentication>
```

then I tried to copy jbossdir/conf/props/jmx-console-users.properties,jmx-console-roles.properties
into users.properties and roles.properies (same dir).

I still get this error:

> ERROR
>   [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule]
>   Failed to load  users/passwords/role
>   files java.io.IOException: No
>   properties file: users.properties or
>   defaults: defaultUsers.properties
>   found

where should I put those files?

Comment: It looks like a workaround was commenting out the whole section, I still do not fully understand what's behind it, does anyone know any good resource on jboss authentication?

Comment: I found this useful: http://www.edc4it.com/2011/05/09/understanding-java-security-and-jaas-part-1/ (3 parts).

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is 2 places where you can put these files:

1. In conf dir, and then you reference to them by:

   `<module-option name="usersProperties">props/jmx-console-users.properties<module-option>`
2. You can put these file in `WEB-INF/classess` dir and reference to them just by name:

   `<module-option name="usersProperties">web-console-users.properties</module-option>`

You can find these in web-console definition. The file with user names is located under: `./deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/WEB-INF/classes/web-console-users.properties`